Rotation angle between two parallel transport (Bishop) frames
I am conducting academic research on steerable needles with multiple sections and I have run into a roadblock. Each needle is composed of two or more sections connected in series and each section can be independently moved. I would like to find the relative axial rotation between two consecutive sections. This paper (Modular robotic platform for precision neurosurgery with a bio-inspired needle: System overview and first in-vivo deployment) is similar to what I am doing and I have been using it as the basis for my mathematical model of the system. However, I am having trouble deriving how to find the rotation angle that I mentioned earlier. The problem is as follows:
Suppose that I have a curve $\gamma(s)$ that is twice differentiable in 3D space, such that a parallel transport frame $F$ can be composed of a tangent vector $T$ and two normal vectors $N_1$ and $N_2$ at every point along the curve. Let $F_{a}$ and $F_{b}$ represent the parallel transport frames at points $s_a$ and $s_b$ along $\gamma$, respectively.
$F_a$ has the tangent vector $T_a$ and the normal vectors $N_{a1}$ and $N_{a2}$.
$F_b$ has the tangent vector $T_b$ and the normal vectors $N_{b1}$ and $N_{b2}$.
Is there a way to find the angle of rotation of $F_b$ with respect to $F_a$ about $T_a$?
For example, say that a steerable needle is represented by $\gamma(s)$. $F_a$ is a fixed world frame that is coincident with the base of the needle such that $T_a$ is pointed along the length of the needle, and $F_b$ is a body frame that is attached to the tip of the needle such that $T_b$ is colinear with $T_a$. The needle undergoes an axial rotation, ie a rotation about $T_a$, such that $F_b$ is now offset from $F_a$ by some angle $\phi$. Can I calculate $\phi$ if I have knowledge of all components of $F_a$ and $F_b$?

Is $\gamma$ a straight line segment? If not, it’s not possible to have a parallel frame where one of the vectors is tangent to the curve. You can see this with a picture. A frame is parallel if and only if it never rotates.
